# selecting a user of every type

Tags: mysql, select

I have a query against two databases that I'm trying to execute. The first table is just user information and is referenced by a privilege table. For my query I'm trying to find a set of super users, they are users that have every current privilege in the privilege table. It is set up as follows:

```
create table MEMBER
  (  id       int           not null,
     name     varchar(10),
     bdate     date,
     sex       char,
     pc_id     int           not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (mid),
   FOREIGN KEY (pc_id) REFERENCES PLEDGECLASS(id))

create table MEMBER_PRIVILEGE
 ( mid      int            not null,
   pid      int            not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (mid,pid),
   FOREIGN KEY (mid) REFERENCES MEMBER(id),
   FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES PRIVILEGE(id))

create table PRIVILEGE
( id       int,
  pname    varchar(15)
  PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

Although obviously the incorrect query, I'm trying to do something equivalent to the following:

```
Select name
From MEMBER,MEMBER_PRIVILEGE
Where id=mid AND pid = ALL (select id
                            From PRIVILEGE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM MEMBER
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM MEMBER_PRIVILEGE LEFT JOIN PRIVILEGE ON MEMBER_PRIVILEGE.pid = PRIVILEGE.id)
   WHERE MEMBER_PRIVILEGE.mid = MEMBER.id AND PRIVILEGE.id IS NULL
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
Select name, (select count(id) from PRIVILIGE) as p_count
  From MEMBER m
  inner join MEMBER_PRIVILEGE mp on (m.id=mp.mid) 
  group by mp.mid having count(*) = p_count;
```